# give access to table through DB link

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I work at a place where we have multiple SQL servers. On each server, I have a user that allows me to create and delete my own tables and access other tables. Usually, i work by creating links back and forth to and from the servers, but so far i haven't had the need to link to tables that i created for myself.

My question is therefore, giving the information above (i hope it's enough), how can i create a table on server2 and access through one of the established DB links from server1? I've been looking at creating DB links, but i've convinced myself that this is not the way to go, as DB links are already established between the servers. I assume it has something to do with granting access.

As of now, i'm not able to access the table from server1 using a query like `select * from table1@server2`, which is the way i normally access remote tables. When i try to do this, i receive the usual error message saying that `Table or view does not exist` and `preceding line from SERVER2`.

Thank you

edit:

When i'm connect to server1 and view all remote tables @ server2, using the query `select * from all_tables@server2`, the table that i created on server2 is visible. However, i'm still not able to `select` from it using the query above.

Comment: give access to server1 user on server2 db link and table1. What command have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the user on the remote database does not have sufficient privileges (that is if you are sure the table exists), and the solution depends on how the DB link was created.

If the DB link was created using a `CONNECT TO someuser IDENTIFIED BY ...` clause, then you can only connect to "someuser", who in your case does not have permission to access the table. In that case it might be advisable to create a new DB link to the correct user.

Otherwise, the DB link has a `CONNECT TO CURRENT_USER` or no `CONNECT BY` clause, which means that the username and credentials you use on server1 are also used for server2. In that case you just need to make sure that user actually has access to the table.

You can read more about remote users in DB links [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#i1007964) (from the Oracle documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The answer was to select from the table using the following query

`SELECT * FROM user2.table1@server2`

where user2 is the user i used to create table1 at server2.